# Roating Image in Java / Processing

Tags: java, rotation, processing

I have started making a basic Asteroids game. 
I am trying to rotate my asteroid while it moves on the Screen.

This is my object code.

```
class Asteroid {
  PImage lrgAsteroid;
  float xpos, ypos;
  float yDirection = 1;
  float xDirection = 1;
  float radians = 0;


  Asteroid() {
    lrgAsteroid = loadImage("largeAsteroid.png");
    xpos = random(0,710);
    ypos = random(0,710);

  }
  void display() {
    image(lrgAsteroid, xpos, ypos);
  }

  void move() {
     imageMode(CENTER);
     translate(xpos, ypos);
     rotate(radians);
     image(lrgAsteroid, xpos, ypos);

     radians += 1;
     xpos += xDirection;
     ypos += yDirection;

  }

}
```

I believe the issue is with the translate statement but I can't work out how to solve it.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation puts the asteroid to its location. There is no need to set the position in [`image()`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html), too.
Draw the image at (0, 0) with [`imageMode(CENTER)`](https://processing.org/reference/imageMode_.html). Rotate the image around its center (0. 0) by [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) and move the image to its location in the window by [`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html):

```java
imageMode(CENTER);
translate(xpos, ypos);
rotate(radians);
image(lrgAsteroid, 0, 0);
```

Note operations like [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) and [`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) define a transformation matrix and multiply the current transformation matrix by the new matrix.